# Скруглить углы у Spinner

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть свой стиль Spinner нашел в инете. Как у него скруглить углы и сделать треугольник красным? Нужно чтобы радиус у corner углов был был 4dp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <color android:color="#fff" />
        <corners android:radius="40dp" />
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#666666" />
                        <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa" android:width="1dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#fff"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Напильником работать умеете?

Comment: [Что делать, если кто-то ответил](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Нужно указать `shape` и свойство этой фигуры `<solid>`, а не `<color>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ddd"/>
            <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="8dp">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:width="12dp" android:height="12dp" android:gravity="center" android:bottom="10dp">
                <rotate
                    android:fromDegrees="45"
                    android:toDegrees="45">
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="#666666" />
                        <stroke android:color="#aaaaaa" android:width="1dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </rotate>
            </item>
            <item android:width="30dp" android:height="10dp" android:bottom="21dp" android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="#ddd"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Вот что получается:

[image: screen]

Comment: А как сделать белый фон? Мне белый фон нужен

Comment: Замените для <solid> вместо #ddd -> #fff (в двух местах, в начале и в конце файла)

Comment: Блин ступил.. получилось, спасибо